# Remove row from php array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have form in 1st page(test.php) as follows

```
 <form method="post" action="newtest.php">
  <input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if(in_array("1", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  alt="1607.00" />
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="2" <?php if(in_array("2", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="1848.00" /> 
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="3" <?php if(in_array("3", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="180.00" />
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="4" <?php if(in_array("4", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="650.00" />
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="5" <?php if(in_array("5", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="495.00" />
     <div class="ph-float">
         <input type="submit" name="button" value="Checkout >>" class="ph-button ph-btn-green fm-submit" disabled="true" >
     </div> 
</form>
```

Based on posted  checkbox selection am displaying Book name,Amount and totalamount  in a table using foreach loop as follows(newtest.php)

```
    <?php     
$product = array();
$product[1] = array('name' => "Text Book of Human Anatomy by B.D.Chaurasiavol 6th edition Vol -I Vol-II Vol-III.", 'price' => 1607);
$product[2] = array('name' => "Nettars Atlas of Anatomy", 'price' => 1848);
$product[3] = array('name' => "Genera Anatomy by B.D.Chaurasia", 'price' => 180);
$product[4] = array('name' => "Inderbir Singh Embryology 10th edition ", 'price' => 650);
$product[5] = array('name' => "Inderbir Singh Histology ", 'price' => 495);

    if(isset($_POST['button']))
{        
       $first = array();
   $second = array();
    foreach ($_POST['product'] as $pId)
     {
    $first[] = $product[$pId]['name'];
    $second[] = $product[$pId]['price']; 
     }
  $bookauthor = count($first);
  $bookprice = count($second);
  $max = ($bookauthor > $bookprice ? $bookauthor : $bookprice);
  echo '<br />';
  echo '<i style="font-color:#000000;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;font-size:21px; padding-left:110px;margin-top:10px"> List of books you have selected:</i>';
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th style="text-align: center">SL No.</th>';
  echo "<th>Book Name</th>";
  echo "<th>Amount in INR</th>";
      echo "<th>Action</th>";
  echo '</tr>';
   $count = 0;
   for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
    $count++;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td style='text-align: center'>{$count}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$first[$i]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$second[$i]}</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='#'><i style='color:#F5F5F5;background:#D52020'>REMOVE</i> </a></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    $total =  array_sum($second);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td colspan='2' style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14px'>Total Amount</td>";
    echo "<td style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;'>{$total}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo '</table>';
    }
```

?>

I want to remove particular row from php when i click on REMOVE link displaying in a same row,
  script below removes from table but i want to remove from php

```
 <script>
$('i').click(function(){
$(this).parent('a').parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can remove using AJAX with php functionality, for e.g. create one array in that include all the books detail i.e 1,2,3,4 and than you want to remove 3 than after click on send whole array of 1,2,3,4 and also send in post to remove=3 and than in ajax .php file remove that 3rd array using php function unset(yourarray[3]);,and that you wit get final array like 1,2,4 and than send back from ajax file to your test.php file and print there ,for this all the things you have to use jQuery+PHP...

Comment: @ Mahendra pumbhadiya can please update your code with my script, because i dont have Proficiency in ajax. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

you may use `closest`

```js
$('i').click(function(){
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>A1</td>
  <td><a href="#"><i>remove</i></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A2</td>
  <td><a href="#"><i>remove</i></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A3</td>
  <td><a href="#"><i>remove</i></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A4</td>
  <td><a href="#"><i>remove</i></a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your answer is perfect but Dev wants to remove using php, for my suggestion Dev wants to use for that AJAX.

Comment: may be. that means remove from db.. however, you give him a solution. so, i don't try to solve.

Comment: @Ahosan Karim Asik thanks for your responce but it will remove from table not from php, and here am not using database all the values am fetching from product array(present in newtest.php) using foreach loop, based on posted checkbox values from test.php. Any updates may appreciated.